# bootstrap-select plugin height issue

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am using the bootstrap-select jquery plugin to whip my select-fields into shape.
Everything is quite nice, however there is one problem.
All the input-fields / buttons have a 50px height.
The my select-class refers to my custom btn-select style:

```
.btn-select {
    .button-variant(@gray; white; white);
    height: 50px;
    .heading-font;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

this fixes the height, but now the bottom margin within the form-group is wrong
When i set the height to "auto", the bottom margin is ok.
What did I miss?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is easy.. If you show your code using jsfiddle...

Comment: yes. but never used jsfiddle before ... ;)

Comment: just add your code,,

Comment: so here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0vmgzncv/6/
( My problem is visible in safari only, since i did not copy all the css and js )

Comment: Is it working fine in IE ,Chrome and Firefox ?

Comment: no, there the styling is just not correct, so you cannnot see the problem.

Comment: the provided jsfiddle is not initializing the bootstrap-select in js. You must add this `$('select').selectpicker();` and update your jsfiddle

Comment: thank you. did that. 
now in safari you can see my issue with the bottom margin.
in firefox/chrome the select item has the correct margin but has the wrong height.